How to use databricks to query SQL Server data on premises?
I want to use Databricks to analyze data that is stored on an on-premises SQL Server. But how can I bring it to databricks?
I tried to configure Lakehouse Federation so I could query on-premises data directly from Databricks. However, due to the different networks, I cannot connect. I assume I’d have to configure an Azure Virtual Network or something similar.
The same issue arises when using the JDBC connector. I cannot simply connect and create a DataFrame from my data because it is on a completely different network.
Using datalake storage?  Let's say I have a simple query that joins 10 tables and outputs just 200 rows. Do I need to bring all those 10 tables to Databricks? Or should I move them to Data Lake Storage first and then to Databricks?
Thanks

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-ntlm-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16
Can you check  and let me know if it helped you?

(spark.read
.format("jdbc")
.option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://servername\sqlinst001;database=dbname;loginTimeout=30;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=NTLM;")
.option("dbtable", "tblname")
.option("user", "username")
.option("password", "password")
.load()
.show()
)
Can you also check if the above??

@DileepRajNarayanThumula - code in a comment, unformatted, is very difficult to read. Please avoid doing this. Also note that there's no programming question here - just a requirement. And several questions, not just one. The OP needs to improve this question.

Please edit to show your work (a [mcve]) and to be specific. Right now, there's no code or any other details - just a requirement and a few questions. Open-ended, discussion-based questions are off-topic.

Without having a complete understanding of your network boundaries, it's difficult to give exact steps on how to connect. Here is the general process I would expect which may help guide you.

Make your on-prem server available to the internet or your Azure (if using Azure Databricks).

I would expect the server to only be available behind a VPN. Since Databricks is a cloud platform any resources you wish to connect to need be available on the cloud. If you are using Azure Databricks this link may help you establish this connection https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/network/classic/on-prem-network


Create an External Connection in Databricks to the server once accessible.

This can be done either programmatically or through the UI. An alternative would be to use the JDBC spark driver directly to communicate with the database.


Create an external catalog to interact with the database like a regular Databricks catalog.

This will map all the tables in the database to an external Databricks table for easier interaction and integration into unity catalog.



